# ASM 5.0.3 byte code throws NoClassDefFoundError oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM 5.0.3 with Websphere 8.5.x and IDM JDK 1.7 to profiling method execution time using **org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter**

Oracle JDBC driver **ojdbc7.jar** is used for creating JDBC. My Application is working fine without adding -javaagent arguments.

When bytecode is modified (via -javaagent), Websphere starts fine but when accessing application it throws **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider** .

I found a link which explains about the issue in detail & shows NoClassDefFoundError happens for certain JVM/driver version combinations

https://plumbr.eu/blog/java/troubleshooting-verifiers-the-rabbit-hole-goes-deep

```
An exception occurred while invoking method setDataSourceProperties on com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl used by resource jdbc/appDatasource : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OraclePKIProvider
 at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.<clinit>(OracleDataSource.java:103)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigHelper.createDataSource(DSConfigHelper.java:747)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.createNewDataSource(WSRdbDataSource.java:3029)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.<init>(WSRdbDataSource.java:1358)
 at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.setDataSourceProperties(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:2653)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 ......
```

### Suggested solution from the link is

Make sure that if the label visit was originally followed by a frame visit, we would insert our instructions after the frame visit, not between the frame and the label.

Can some one explain "How to achieve this using ASM bytecode?"

## Update1 - Attached AdviceAdapter Code

```
package com.abc.agent.adapter;

import com.abc.jm.TMConstants;
import com.abc.jm.TMLog;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Label;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.Type;
import com.abc.org.objectweb.asm.commons.AdviceAdapter;

public class DriverMethodAdviceAdapter extends AdviceAdapter  {

    private String methodName;
    private String className;
    private String description;
    private boolean isConnectMethod;

    private static final String INTERFACE_DRIVER_CONNECT_METHOD_DESC = "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;";

    private int okFlag =  newLocal(Type.BOOLEAN_TYPE); 
    Label startFinally = new Label();

    public DriverMethodAdviceAdapter(int access , MethodVisitor mv , String methodName, String description, String className, int classFileVersion){
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, mv, access, methodName, description);
        this.className = className;
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.description = description;
        this.isConnectMethod = false;

        if(methodName.equals("connect") && description.equals(INTERFACE_DRIVER_CONNECT_METHOD_DESC)){
            isConnectMethod = true;
        }
    }

    public void visitCode() {
        super.visitCode(); 
        mv.visitLabel(startFinally);
    }

    protected void onMethodEnter(){
         if(isConnectMethod){
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);

            mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/abc/agent/trace/Tracer", "jdbcConnectionMethodBegin", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z", false);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, okFlag);
         }
    }

    protected void onMethodExit(int opcode){
        if(opcode!=ATHROW) {
            onFinally(opcode);
        }
    }

    public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals){
        Label endFinally = new Label();
        mv.visitTryCatchBlock(startFinally, endFinally, endFinally, null);
        mv.visitLabel(endFinally);
        onFinally(ATHROW);
        mv.visitInsn(ATHROW);
        mv.visitMaxs(maxStack+4, maxLocals);
    }

    private void onFinally(int opcode){
         if(isConnectMethod){
            mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP); // This is return object 
            mv.visitLdcInsn(className);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(methodName);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(description);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, okFlag);
            mv.visitLdcInsn(opcode);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/abc/agent/trace/Tracer", "jdbcConnectionMethodEnd", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)V", false);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the flags **ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES** for ClassWriter  and **ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES | ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES** for ClasseReader.accept().

Comment: The conclusions of that article are wrong. First, the main conclusion should be that you should not mess around with bytecode instrumentation, if you don’t know what you are doing. Further, the information is outdated, HotSpot does not fall back to another verifier since Java 7, unless you enforce it with a special option (and then, it’s not the JVM’s fault if that backfires). Also, if incorrect stack map frames are the problem, it could be easily solved using either, the right ASM option or just a different class file version, *or* adapt the visitor, but, well, see the first conclusion…

Comment: Hi Holger, thanks for your notes. I have found another APM tool https://www.nudge-apm.com/releases-probe-java/#v3_2_1  which also shows a bug fix related to the same issue. - class not found ‘oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider’ with some oracle JDBC drivers. Seems there is way to fix this bug

Comment: There is a way to fix this bug, for sure. There are also ways to avoid creating such bugs in the first place. It depends on what you are actually doing with the byte code. Since I don’t know what you are doing, I can’t tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Holger, Included the bytecode changes. Do you find the problem cause.? Please note that, the same code works fine, if i am using other drivers classes12.zip , ojdbc14.jar etc.

Comment: `EXPAND_FRAMES|SKIP_FRAMES` is a strange combination of flags. When you are using `COMPUTE_FRAMES` for the writer, i.e. recalculating all frames from scratch, it makes sense to use `SKIP_FRAMES` on the reader as you are going to ignore the frames anyway, but what is `EXPAND_FRAMES` supposed to do? Expand the frames you are skipping?

Comment: Hi Holger  Thank you for the reply.  Do you suggest only SKIP_FRAMES  on the reader?

Comment: Yes, only `SKIP_FRAMES` is needed. But that’s not causing the problem. Are you changing the class version during Instrumentation?

Comment: No. Not changing class version during instrumentation.Used oracle driver class version is 51 (1.7 java)

Comment: So the original class file should be working with stack frames. It would be helpful to see the original and transformed byte code. I can’t see anything obvious in the `DriverMethodAdviceAdapter`…

Comment: Thank you Holger for your kind response.  Let me compare the original & modified byte code. This issue happens with AspectJ + Oracle driver too. Please refer these links - (https://support.quest.com/de-de/foglight/kb/137200) , (https://support.quest.com/de-de/foglight/kb/137200)

Comment: sorry missed this link - http://info.michael-simons.eu/2006/07/26/oracle-jdbc-driver-und-aspectj/ for AspectJ + Oracle driver